# Creating functions to chain promises correctly

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to get Promise chaining working for me correctly.

I believe the problem boils down to understanding the difference between:

```
promise.then(foo).then(bar);
```

and:

```
promise.then(foo.then(bar));
```

In this situation I am writing both `foo` and `bar` and am trying to get the signatures right. `bar` does take a return value that is produced by `foo`.

I have the latter working, but my question is what do I need to do to get the former working?

Related to the above is the full code (below). I don't have the different logs printed in the order I am expecting (expecting `log1`, `log2`, `log3`, `log4`, `log5`, but getting `log3`, `log4`, `log5`, `log1`, `log2`). I am hoping as I figure the above I will get this working right as well.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function listPages(queryUrl) {
  var promise = Promise.resolve();

  promise = promise
    .then(parseFeed(queryUrl)
      .then(function (items) {

      items.forEach(function (item) {
        promise = promise.then(processItem(transform(item)))
                    .then(function() { console.log('log1');})
                    .then(function() { console.log('log2');});
      });

    }).then(function() {console.log('log3')})
  ).then(function() {console.log('log4')})
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error, error.stack);
  });
  return promise.then(function() {console.log('log5');});
};
```

Comment: The second one is simply wrong. `then` takes a callback as its argument, not a promise.

Comment: @Bergi - If I want to provide another promise to the `then`, do I need to just make sure that the callback returns the promise?

Comment: @Vineet yup, you need to pass a function that returns a Promise, not the Promise itself.

Comment: @Vineet: Yes, make callback that returns the promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between `promise.then(foo).then(bar);` and `promise.then(foo.then(bar));`?

The second one is simply wrong. The `then` method takes a callback as its argument, not a promise. That callback might return a promise, so the first one is equivalent to

```
promise.then(function(x) { return foo(x).then(bar) })
```

(assuming that `foo` returns a promise as well).

---

Your whole code appears to be messed up a bit. It should probably read

```
function listPages(queryUrl) {
    return parseFeed(queryUrl)
    .then(function (items) {
        var promise = Promise.resolve();
        items.forEach(function (item) {
            promise = promise.then(function() {
                console.log('log1');
                return processItem(transform(item));
            }).then(function() {
                console.log('log2');
            });
        });
        return promise;
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('log3')
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('error: ', error, error.stack);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you moved the `var promise = Promise.resolve();` inside the callback? Wouldn't it work if it were outside? (I agree your code is cleaner, but I am just trying to figure out my gaps in understanding as well).

Comment: @Vineet: Yes, you should keep variables as local as possible. It would have worked to initialise it in an outer scope as well, but in your original code you did `return promise` from the `listPages` function, which does not work when `promise` is assigned only in the asynchronous callback. One even could've (should've?) completely avoided the variable and the assignment and used `reduce` instead of `forEach`. The important part is that the `promise` is returned from the `then` callback.